# HTACCESS issue with question mark in the url, ? remains

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm using the wordpress redirection plugin as i don't have access to the .htaccess file.

I'm trying to redirect urls with a `?` in them, I have the following redirect set up, but the `?` is left in the url.

`/(.*) \?post_type=resource(.*)`
I have also tried 
`/\?post_type=resource(.*)`

I'm redirecting to `/resources/`

But this url http://www.example.com/?post_type=resource&p100

Redirects to http://www.example.com/?/resources/

Any ideas?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by adding `^` before the source url

`^/\?post_type=resource(.*)`